Electric flux through a surface due to a point charge which lies on that surface itself
Take a point charge lying on a sheet of finite area. Is the flux undefined in this case or is it zero? Please help as on most of the physics sites, this is highly debated.
My approach: Since the charge lies on the surface through which the flux has to be calculated, the field of the charge becomes undefined since the distance between them (surface and charge) becomes equal to zero.

Have you tried evaluating the integral yourself?

I mean on the sheet

Just started learning gauss' law @VincentThacker, not that good at evaluating things on my own

@Baksish why did you refer to gauss law ? Does the sheet form a closed surface (because gauss law deals with closed surface)?

Gauss' law, electric flux etc etc.

How did you try to solve this question ?

Since the charge lies on the surface through which the flux has to be calculated, the field of the charge becomes undefined since the distance between them becomes equal to zero

Add your last comment to your question: you should show how you tried to solve the problem and, if stuck, where. As for the problem itself, you took the wrong turn thinking about a single point. Think of the flux through any spherical shell centred at the point charge. How does the flux through the surface area element $d\mathbf{A}$ depend on the radius of the sphere? Then contract the shell until it shrinks down to an infinitesimal radius and area.

@kkm-stillwaryofSEpromises How is that in any way related to the flux through the surface? No offence intended

Exactly half of the flux flows through each half-shell at each side of the plane. If your integral converges in the limit $r\to 0$, you'll get a finite flux, hopefully $0$. It's easy to understand visually: imagine the field lines of $\mathbf{E}$, none of which crosses the plane. If it diverges, then the flux blows up to infinity, i.e. undefined. That'll give you a physical sense of the problem, which microwaving a pre-cooked theorem from vector calculus won't. Mathematically, you can complete the definition, as Ján said. Physically, you can't. That's what I'm pushing you toward. :)

@kkmmistrustsSE the flux should be $\frac{Q}{2\epsilon_0}$ and not $0$.

I'm sorry for my error everybody, and thank you @Rϵlaτινιτy for spotting it. Of course the setting is not symmetric "above" and "below" the plane, as for each $\mathrm{d}s$, the $\mathbf{E}$ is scalar-multiplied by the normal vector to the former, so that the sign of every integrated infinitesimal is everywhere positive when the field is non-zero and is directed outside through the sphere being contracted.

The usual Gauss-Ostrogradskii theorem (relating electric field flux with electric charge) holds for charge that is either inside or outside the closed surface. If non-zero charge is on the surface, then the surface integral (giving the flux) is not uniquely defined. One can try to complete the definition in various ways, but as far as I know, this is not standardized.
This does not seem to be really needed in any practical use of the theorem. Just use a surface that does not have any point charge on it.

Thanks mate, helped me clear my doubt
